# Error message when loading any package in R

Tags: r

please, can anybody help? when I try to load any package in R the following message appears:

> library(ggpubr)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggpubr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.5.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.2 is required

> library(rstatix)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rstatix’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.5.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.2 is required

> library(tidyverse)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
> .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
> call: NULL
> error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.5.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.2 is required

I need suggestions about how to solve this.

Comment: Try `install.packages("vctrs")` and try again?

Answer (score 2):

This error often occurs after you’ve updated packages, but installation of some packages or dependencies failed. The failed installations, in turn, are often caused by RStudio’s diagnostics. For instance, if an open script calls a function using the double colon operator (e.g., `dplyr::mutate()`), even if you haven’t run the script, the linter will load the package namespace and its dependencies. Which interferes with attempts to update those packages. See [this comment in a related thread on the RStudio GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/8072#issuecomment-1187683874).

To get around this, you can try:

- **close all scripts,** then start a fresh session, then run `install.packages("vctrs")` (or whatever the offending package is) in the console before opening any scripts.
- or, run `install.packages("vctrs")` in RGUI instead of RStudio.
- or, [turn off R diagnostics in RStudio](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/8072#issuecomment-1413801793) before updating.