# Problem loading dplyr package: problem with name space "vctrs"

Tags: r, dplyr, error-handling, loading

I encounter the following problem while loading the dplyr package:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.5.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.2 is required
```

How can I fix this this issue?

I don't know how I should start fixing this problem.

Comment: This may also be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75775986/17303805

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run

```
remove.packages('vctrs')
install.packages('vctrs')
```

If this nor any of the solutions in the duplicates work, try

1. Close R;
2. Open a terminal window;
3. Run `R -q -e "install.packages('vctrs')"`
4. Restart R.

This should (always?) work.