# vctrs package 0.38 is required for ggplot2

Tags: r

When I use

```
library(ggplot2)
```

in r I got the following output

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.3.3 is already loaded, but >= 0.3.8 is required

I tried to update vctrs package but it didn't work. Could anyone please help me how to fix this problem so that I can use my ggplot2 package?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75876066/12957340

Comment: The current version of vctrs is 0.6.3 so you are some way behind - what version of R are you using (output of `R.version`) ?

Comment: @jared_mamrot I used that but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @neilfws I use R-4.1.3 .

Comment: You should (need to) update R.