# Recurring error with R projects, tidyverse, rlang

Tags: r, tidyverse

I teach data skill workshops to students, in the format of sending out a folder with an R project, data, and an R notebook to work through. The R Project file is used with the `here` function to make loading data easier.

Typically we open a workshop with something along the lines of:

```
pacman::p_load(here, readxl, dplyr, janitor, Quandl, xts, lubridate, urca, forecast, tidyverse, vars)

data <- read_csv(here("Data", "data_lecture2.csv"))
```

So, they load all their packages, then load their data from the `Data` folder.

A problem many students (and myself) are having is `tidyverse` refusing to load. After much trial and error, involving uninstalling and reinstalling it in the Packages window in RStudio or manually from their file explorer, we eventually get it working.

It seems linked with an issue with the `rlang` package. After the repeated uninstalling/reinstalling finally does something, we get a new error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
.onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
call: NULL
error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.6 is already loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
```

I've gone in and done a similar uninstall/reinstall process to update `rlang` several times, but it similarly comes back on certain project files.

What stands out with this is that it depends on the R Project and Notebook in question. Sometimes I'll have the issue, swap to another, and it doesn't have any effect there. I did recently update from R version 4.2.2 to 4.2.3, but the error predates this.

Is the issue one related to how R Project files work? How can I manage my files to avoid it?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75776237/17303805

Comment: I went through this when I taught a workshop not long ago as well. I think it is caused by rlang already being attached, so it can't be installed over. I had to tell everyone to install rlang by itself in a fresh R session.