# How to install a Package

Tags: r

Im trying to install `heplots` with RStudio with this code:

```
install.packages("heplots")
library("heplots")
data(Rohwer)
head(Rohwer)
```

But when I do, I get the error `Error: package ‘broom’ could not be loaded`. Any idea how to fix this I tried `install.packages("broom")` but that didn't work.
Here is what the console says:

```
Warning: package ‘heplots’ was built under R version 4.2.3Loading required package: broom
Warning: package ‘broom’ was built under R version 4.2.3Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘broom’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.6 is already loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
Error: package ‘broom’ could not be loaded
```

Comment: What do you mean by “installing broom didn’t work”? Did you start a fresh session of R, install broom (I.e. install the missing dependency separately), and then try again?

Comment: I restarted RStudio, downloaded broom, but I still the same error

Comment: Try updating the `rlang` package.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75776237/17303805

Comment: Specifically (modifying MartinGal's suggestion, reinforcing zephryl's suggestion): close R and RStudio, all of them, do not leave a session open; restart R; `install.packages("rlang")`; only once that succeeds, try again to install broom. Why? When a package is being used by an R session (even if only for a help page!), then it can be difficult to update it in-place. It might be possible to `detach("package:rlang", unload=TRUE)` and try it that way, but there are many ways that even that is insufficient, so in general the recommendation is to stop _all R sessions_, restart, and install again.

Comment: Do this> track down any .Rdata files that might be loading packages without you knowing it. Then start a new session and issue the call: `update.packages(ask=TRUE)`. (It's going to take some time unless you have a small number of installed packages or have been very careful to stay current.) Then issue the command: `install.packages("heplots", dependencies=TRUE)`